# What is a fractional-order circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Despite some basic knowledge in electronics, and maybe because of my non-english tongue, I don't understand the term "fractional-order circuit", that I've read on a paper. Could a specialist explains the meaning of this term, as well as the applications of this field ?

That seems to be an [emergent theme in EE](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5642494) (or resurgent) ?

Also [Stability Analysis of Fractional-Order Circuits](http://www.fcaj.webs.com/Download/JFCAA-Vol.3,%20No.1.pdf)

Comment: Do you have a link to where you came across this term?

Comment: @Andyaka I guess this is it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional-order_system

Comment: Yes. But, as I tried to explain, I'd like an explanation for curious people, especially about what it is used for.

Comment: @JCLL - I think you need to explain how you think it may be related to electrical engineering.

Comment: @Andy : ok I added a link to IEEE advertisment.

Comment: I couldn't see anything that mentioned a fractional-order circuit - more help needed to understand your question.

Comment: @aka : see the link (emergent theme) above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Nonlinear Noninteger Order Systems: Theory and Applications' by Paolo "Arena, R. Caponetto, M Porto, L. Fortuna, M." Porto (2001) Is a good book in this area.

Areas of applicability are: Non-inductive transmission lines, 1/f noise spectra, polarization effects in dielectrics, diffusion effects and a lot of acoustic effects.  Some interesting control theory arises from the use of non-integer order control systems, the most well known is CRONE (french acronym for Command Robuste d'Ordre Non-Entier) - it provides for damping that is insensitive to the parameters of the system being controlled.  There are even non linear \$PID\$ systems, of the form \$PI^\lambda D^\mu \$.  Image processing with variable gamma is also a very common thing that people experience.

Answer (score 1):

Fractional-Order Circuit is applied Fractional-Calculus to Circuit Analysis

- [Commonly used for modeling bio-electrodes for cardiac tissue interfacing.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5160719)
- [Offer more robustness than integer order control in PID controllers, using Fractional Integrators and Differetinators.](http://www.fcaj.webs.com/Download/JFCAA-Vol.3,%20No.1.pdf)

Not much knowledge in this field but heard something about Resistoductance, which is one component that incorporates fractional-order dynamics. It's a "linear electrical circuit element that posses the characteristics between an ohmic resistor and an inductor"

[image]

Fractional Integrator and Differentiator Equations:

[image]

[image]